# How to handler Special characters needs 2 bytes in UTF8 sqlldr ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

How to handler Special characters needs 2 bytes in UTF8 in sql loader Oracle

The character is show and store correctly, "á" for intance. But, the row that contains this type of character is slides to next column of the table in data base. The main problem y that lost position because special character needs 2 bytes.

How Can I keep the length of value column?

file.txt

```
4351 LUISA  F32345
2312 JOSÉ   M67868
```

file.ctl

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
INFILE file.txt
APPEND INTO TABLE USERAPP
( ID   POSITION(1:5)   CHAR,
  NAME POSITION(6:12)  CHAR,
  GEN  POSITION(13:13) CHAR,
  CODE POSITION(14:20) CHAR)
```

then in table

```
ID   NAME   GEN CODE 
4351 LUISA  F   32345
2312 JOSÉ       M67868
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What does "lost position" mean?  The `length` function in Oracle returns the length of a string in characters, not bytes, so every character has a length of 1 regardless of the number of bytes required to store it.  What is the database character set?  Are you trying to store a character in a database whose character set doesn't support it?

Comment: I don't understand either. What `length` has to do with sql loader and the characterset ? can you provide a clear example of what problem do you have ? Sorry, but the question is very difficult to understand

Comment: Hello guys,  my problem is like row of JOSÉ ... this character "É " alter sql loder process, then take more of one byte, and lost setting that I did it.

Comment: @JustinCave I hope you can understand the problem

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I hope you can understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem, you cannot use position by char:
"The start and end arguments to the POSITION parameter are interpreted in bytes, even if character-length semantics are in use in a datafile. "

Try this way:

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8 LENGTH CHAR
INFILE file.txt
APPEND INTO TABLE USERAPP
(
 ID   CHAR(5),
  NAME CHAR(7),
  GEN  CHAR(1)
  CODE CHAR(7)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I've been looking for a solution to upload files that are:

- UTF8 encoded
- fixed character (yes, character, not fixed-bytes)
  width

All other options produced displacement on fields following accented characters, or truncate the data.
To summarize:

- Use char semantics in the table receiving the data.
- Use a database character set that supports Unicode

This is my control file:

```
LOAD DATA 
    CHARACTERSET UTF8 LENGTH SEMANTICS CHAR
    INFILE '_FILENAME_' 
APPEND
INTO TABLE TEST_UTF8
(
    NUM_SEGMENT CHAR(3),
    MESSAGE CHAR(5),
    LOT_NUMBER CHAR(5)
)
```

This is the table:

```
create table TEST_UTF8
(
    NUM_SEGMENT varchar2(3 char)
    , MESSAGE varchar2(5 char)
    , LOT_NUMBER varchar2(5 char) 
);
```

This is the sample data:

[Screen snapshot of the data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KSqb.png)

```
001aeiou20350
002á    20350
003áéíóú20350
```

[Hex View of the input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYMrt.png)

This is the result in the Oracle table:

```
NUM_SEGMENT|MESSAGE|LOT_NUMBER|
-----------+-------+----------+
001        |aeiou  |20350     |
002        |á      |20350     |
003        |áéíóú  |20350     |
```

As you can see, the file has been splitted into columns based on characters, not bytes, and accented characters have been interpreted correctly by the database.

I would like to thank Gábor for suggesting this syntax, that I've not found it anywhere in the Oracle documentation. I would like also to upvote, but I cannot because I've not the required reputation yet. I would appreciate if somebody can upvote, this have been extremely useful.

tags: Oracle, SQL*Loader, UTF8

Added on 24th october 2021:

If you mix "fieldname" POSITION(a:b) specifiers, with "fieldname CHAR(x)" syntax, you must put the tables imported via "fieldname CHAR(x)" before the tables imported via POSITION specifers. Otherwise the behaviour of SQL*Loader is erratic.